# Plugin QGIS- Principal problem: find a function that recognizes the word even only from prefixes

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, python-script-tool, plugins

WORK SCHEME
The issues are **highlighted**.
User input for the plugin:

• a raster map with information on the depth of the water reached by a rain / flood event;

• a polygonal vector file with buildings that will have a column in the attributes table (eg "definizion") describing the typology (Baracca, Residenziale, Serra, Scuola).

[image]

**The ideal would be for the plugin to be able to read the column of this vector file automatically without indicating what name the column has.**, so as to use the code `if ("definizion" = 'Baracca', 1, IF ("definizion" = 'Ciminiera', 1, IF ("definizion" = ''Serbatoio per usi industriali (carburanti, gas ...)', 3,0)))`.

As you can see from the line of code (obviously not complete), to simplify the procedure I will associate the buildings / structures with the numbers that represent each category. With a search I have selected all the possible words that a user could have in the "definition" column of his vector file.

[image]

**I would like to find a procedure that allows me to automatically associate a number to words chosen by me, do not do it by hand for all words.** The numbers for the building categories are associated like this:

```
Id_buildings = {
    "Residential": 1,
    "Commercial": 2,
    "Industrial": 3,
    "Transport": 4,
    "Infrastructure roads": 5,
    "Agriculture": 6}
```

The column with information on the user's buildings ("definition") will most likely have names other than those imposed by me, or names that have only prefixes similar to mine (RESIDENZa / RESIDENZiale). The code above works if the word is exactly the one entered by me, but **it would be ideal to find a function that recognizes the word even only from prefixes and that still associates the number with that word.**
Once this is done the plugin should add to the vector a column with only the identification numbers of the categories mentioned above.

[image]

do you know a library with a similar work done that I can find the script for?

Comment: I admit I do not fully understand what you want. Do you want to create a dictionary of "word" -> "value" mappings and calculate a new column from that? What relevance does the raster have?

Answer (score 0):

If you're always going to be looking for a small set of values, and the leading character values are reliable, then perhaps you could try organizing your lookup table/dictionary a little differently.  For example, modify your dictionary to something like this:

```
Id_buildings = {
    1: ("Residential", "residen"),
    2: ("Commercial", "comme"),
    3: ("Transport", "transp"),
    4: ("Infrastructure roads", "roads"),
    5: ("Agriculture", "agric")
}
```

Then you can use built in `str` object methods like `.beginswith()` to determine if the string you've encountered is in `Id_buildings[<some number>][1]`.  If it is, then you can call the key or whatever replacement value you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

My first approach would be to read all the entries in the `definizion` field and make a list of the unique entries. It's then pretty straightforward to create a dictionary that associates an integer with each unique entry.

Complication 1 - might the entries contain non-uniform choices about captialization? If so, then just apply the lower() function to the entries before comparing them.

Complication 2 - might there be misspellings? This is harder to resolve reliably, but you could try the get_close_matches() function from the difflib package.

Complication 3 - do the assigned integer codes need to match across multiple layer files? This is a lot harder to address. If you have all the input files that need to match against at the start, you can just process them all together, but that seems unlikely. A reasonable alternative might be to hash each entry down to an integer. This doesn't guarantee uniqueness, but depending on the length of the hash can give as high a probability as you wish.